# MariaDB MySQL query is much longer if datetime in query has timezone, but very fast if no timezone is added - why?

Tags: mysql, datetime, indexing, mariadb

I have a table in MariaDB (MySQL) that has `start_date_time` field of type `DATETIME` (no TZ stored) .

When I do request as follows, I get

```
MariaDB [db]> explain 
SELECT * 
FROM mytable  
WHERE start_date_time>= '2021-03-04 00:00:00+00:00' 
  AND start_date_time<='2021-03-04 11:08:00+00:00' 
ORDER BY start_date_time;
+------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | mytable  | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 5       | NULL | 4504011 | Using where |
+------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

which takes a long time to complete in practice. The table contains many years of data and the request takes ~30 seconds, looks similar to a full scan.

However if I just drop `+00:00` in query times (`2021-03-04 00:00:00+00:00` becomes `2021-03-04 00:00:00`), the explain looks as follows and query is much faster:

```
MariaDB [db]> explain 
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE start_date_time>= '2021-03-04 00:00:00' 
  AND start_date_time<='2021-03-04 11:08:00' 
ORDER BY  start_date_time;
+------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | mytable  | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 5       | NULL |    1 | Using where |
+------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

I would like to understand why this difference in execution time happens. Ideally I would like to keep time zone in queries to avoid any kind of assumption, conversions or misunderstandings of Timezone between database and client.

**UPDATE**
As requested I also provide the JSON-formatted EXPLAIN below

1st (slow) query

```
 {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "mytable",
      "access_type": "index",
      "possible_keys": ["PRIMARY"],
      "key": "PRIMARY",
      "key_length": "5",
      "used_key_parts": ["start_date_time"],
      "rows": 11403954,
      "filtered": 100,
      "attached_condition": "mytable.start_date_time >= '2021-03-04 00:00:00+00:00' and mytable.start_date_time <= '2021-03-04 11:08:00+00:00'"
    }
  }
}
```

2nd (fast) query

```
| {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "mytable",
      "access_type": "range",
      "possible_keys": ["PRIMARY"],
      "key": "PRIMARY",
      "key_length": "5",
      "used_key_parts": ["start_date_time"],
      "rows": 1,
      "filtered": 100,
      "attached_condition": "mytable.start_date_time >= '2021-03-04 00:00:00' and mytable.start_date_time <= '2021-03-04 11:08:00'"
    }
  }
}
```

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE:

 CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `start_date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  ... more fields...
  PRIMARY KEY (`start_date_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: The second query does not have the `ORDER BY start_date_time`. I assume that's a typo?

Comment: Also, please indicate: 1) what's the primary key of the table, and 2) the list of indexes ("keys" in MariaDB lingo) the table has.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support datetime literals including timezones. See [Date and Time Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a case of index misuse due to implicit type conversion. When no type conversion happens, it scans index range - finds two boundary values and returns everything between them. If it has to apply some kind of conversion function to stored values, then it scans the whole index from beginning to end and tests every row against the given predicates.

I think you may try to explicitly convert the constants in the query to `DATETIME` in order to confirm this conjecture. Like:

```
  WHERE start_date_time >= cast('2021-03-04 00:00:00+00:00' as datetime)
  AND start_date_time <= cast('2021-03-04 11:08:00+00:00' as datetime)
```

Though, the above will probably discard the timezone information. I believe, something like `convert_tz('2021-03-04 00:00:00', '+00:00', @@GLOBAL.time_zone)` would handle that even better.

Answer (score 0):

A likely answer:  `'2021-03-04 00:00:00+00:00'` is just a string, but `'2021-03-04 00:00:00'` is recognized as a `DATETIME`.  That is, MySQL does not honor the timezone appendage, not in that syntax nor the syntax with "T" and/or "Z".

Since it is a string, the column may need to be converted to a string before comparing; the inhibits the use of any `INDEX`.  Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` of both queries.  Perhaps it will point out what I suspect.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It sounds like you have `PRIMARY KEY(start_date_time)`, but I need to be sure.

`DATETIME` is not adjusted for timezone by MySQL; `TIMESTAMP` is.  See (at least) `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';`

Comment: This is my understanding too. The manual section on [Date and Time Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html) does not include any mention of strings with timezones.

Comment: @Rick James, I have added the information you requested to the question.

Comment: @Nick what about TZ when you query database from a client that is on a computer with different TZ than DB server is in? Will timestamps in the query be TZ-corrected or would match database contents precisely?

Comment: @AskarIbragimov - I added a paragraph about "adjusting for TZ".

Comment: Thank you! How can I be sure that "Since it is a string, the column may need to be converted to a string before comparing; the inhibits the use of any INDEX" - happens?

Comment: @AskarIbragimov - I have not thought of a conclusive test case.  Suggest you remove the TZ from those strings and see if it feels faster.